# CSS Динамическое изменение фона

Tags: css

Есть такой кусок кода

```
    .box {
        background: url("image.jpg");
        height: 89vh;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;

    }
```

Мне нужно что бы сюда загружалась картинка от названия переменной объекта

th:src="'/'+${sess.name}+'.jpg'"

Как мне это реализовать? Спасибо

Comment: На чистом CSS - никак, но вы можете это сделать через JS `document.querySelector('.box').style.backgroundImage = \`url(/${sess.name}.png)\``;

Comment: Здравствуйте, De.Minov
Можете подсказать как правильно реализовать это в коде?

Вот сама html
            <div class="box">
                        <h1><span th:text="${sess.name}"> </span></h1>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <h4><span th:text="${sess.text}"></span></h4>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <h5><span th:text="${#temporals.format(sess.create, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"> ></span></h5>
                    </div>

Comment: Что за `th:text`? В метках вы указали только [tag:css].

Answer (score 0):

Нагуглив нашёл [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146729/7692602), для блока `.box` укажите

```
th:style="'background-image:url('+@{sess.name}+');'"
```